# Content View not created on loading listview on fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to put an "Onclicklistener" on my list view, but the logcat says "Content view not created"

Here is my code:

**ListPlacesFragment.java**

```
   public class ListPlacesFragment extends ListFragment {

   String[] countries = new String[] {
        "Home", "Places", "Maps", "Reviews", "Facebook"
   };    

   int[] flags = new int[]{
        R.drawable.homeg,R.drawable.placesg,R.drawable.mapg,R.drawable.reviewg,R.drawable.fbg
   };

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_places_fragment, container, false);


    List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();        

    for(int i =0; i <5;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("txt", countries[i]);
        hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );            
        aList.add(hm);        
    }

    // Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.imagePreview,R.id.textDesc};        

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.list_item, from, to);       

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
    switch(position) {
            case 0: 
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://facebook.com/")));

                break;
            case 1:
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://twitter.com/")));

                break;
    }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
   }



  }
```

I have read some previous thread about this, but what the previous members' trying to achieve is different from mine. Another one is it was declared after declaring the view. Please tell me what is wrong. Here is my Logcat. Thanks!

http://shrib.com/content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer it. After looking at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) I found out that the code for setting up the listview must be in onActivityCreated.

```
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

   List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();        

    for(int i =0; i <5;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("txt", countries[i]);
        hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );            
        aList.add(hm);        
    }

    // Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.imagePreview,R.id.textDesc};        

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.list_item, from, to);       

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
    switch(position) {
            case 0: 
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://facebook.com/")));

                break;
            case 1:
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://twitter.com/")));

                break;
    }
        }
    });
}
```